# Getting a hash in URL when using BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

As I've understood it BrowserRouter from react-router v4 should not use # in the url anymore, but for me, the hash is still added for some strange reason...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import app from './reducers/reducers.js';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {polyfill} from 'es6-promise'

import App from './components/app.jsx';

let store = createStore(app, {
    setAuthenticated: false
    },
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware
    ));

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={'/'}>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Should I not be "hash-free" when using the BrowserRouter? Or is redux somehow affecting the BrowserRouter?

Comment: Some general tips: Try removing your node_modules folder and re-running `npm install`. Hard refresh in your browser by holding Shift and then hitting the refresh button. If you have any other caching, make sure it's getting emptied.

Comment: Solved some of the issues, thanks. Still a problem though when I use google oAuth and get the callback and the redirect the user to '/', then I still get the hash...

Answer (score 0):

just solved the same problem:
check if you're using components, that work directly with hash (such as createHashHistory in my situation)
sorry for late answer)